# Converting Json that returns multiple class types in c#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

So i've started work on a project for myself and i'm using the AlphaVantage API( https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/)
However i've run into an issue where they return an object structured roughly like this:

```
{[Meta Data, {{
  "1. Information": "Weekly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
  "2. Symbol": "ko",
  "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-12-13",
  "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
}}]}
{[Weekly Time Series, {{
  "2019-12-13": {
    "1. open": "54.3000",
    "2. high": "54.5500",
    "3. low": "53.6600",
    "4. close": "54.4200",
    "5. volume": "54644469"
  },
  "2019-12-13": {
    "1. open": "54.3000",
    "2. high": "54.5500",
    "3. low": "53.6600",
    "4. close": "54.4200",
    "5. volume": "54644469"
  }
}}]}
```

Which would be structured as two separate objects like so:

```cs
public class MetaData
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastRefresh { get; set; }
    public String TimeZone { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public List<ValueData> entry { get; set; }
}
public class ValueData
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
}
```

My question is what's the best practice for deserializing this? i tried doing so to just a object type, and inspected it with a debugger and it contained 2 separate structures.

Comment: is this valid Json?

Comment: No, not it is not @geo

Comment: But it only seems like OP has a copy/ paste error, calling https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo shows me valid Json

Comment: @MindSwipe Yes. Then this cannot be deserialized.
bailey-dunn Share a valid JSON.

Comment: As an alternative, there seems to be a ready to use lib available: https://github.com/LutsenkoKirill/AlphaVantage.Net (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

In C# there are multiple ways of deserializing JSON to an object. The most popular is [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) also known as `Json.NET`, then there is the [`System.Text.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) API in .NET Core 3.0 which you can use. Here is an example for both:

Json.NET

```cs
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>(jsonString);
```

Where `Type` is your underlying base type (which seems to be just a class containing a property for `Meta Data` and `Weekly Time Series`) and `jsonString` is your downloaded JSON. Alphavantage uses spaces in their property names, so you'll need to use the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute and specify a name

Alternatively .NET Core 3:

```cs
var obj = JsonSerializer.Parse<Type>(jsonString);
```

Where once again `Type` is your underlying base type and where once again you'll need to use an attribute to properly map the properties, but this time you need the [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

But if you don't want to go through the hassle of creating and testing the classes yourself, you could look at [Alphavantage.Net](https://github.com/LutsenkoKirill/AlphaVantage.Net) which, while untested, could save you a lot of time. Shoutout to [Christoph Lütjen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2085502/christoph-l%c3%bctjen) for linking it in the comments

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I am currently using the newtonsoft library for this. However if you look at the closing brackets for the meta data its actually two separate objects of different structures being sent. So my issue is i dont know how to deserialize to two different objects. I tried deserializing to a class containing each of the classes and it just returned null.

Comment: @BaileyDunn the JSON you copied into your question is also invalid, commas are missing, quotation marks are missing and you have 2 root objects, please edit your question and update the JSON to your actual JSON